# System calls using Popen in a for loop fail after the first iteration fine in a parallel environment using mpi4py

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, mpi, hpc

A simple script below will show that Popen in the simplest case of just sending "ECHO" in a loop only works in the first iteration (run on IBM iDataplex x86 system with RHEL 5). The first iteration it can make as many calls to Popen with no issues but after that only 4 processes can have access to Popen. Therefore, if there is a call that requires passing information to all processes (eg. allgather so a barrier is required) then nothing is passed because stdo='' (empty string) for all but 4 processes.  If the while loop is used, then it never exits because gets caught in the loop on all but 4 processes. Is this specific to this system or would anyone here have any idea what is going on with this??

It works completely fine if run on 4 processes or less.

```
from mpi4py import MPI
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
num_proc = comm.Get_size()
if rank == 0:
    start_time = MPI.Wtime()
for i in range(10):
    stdo = ''
    cmd = ['echo','HELLO']
    # while stdo == '':
    a = Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
    stdo, stder = a.communicate("Input")
    a.wait()
    if stdo != "HELLO\n":
        print "Rank", rank, "ITER: ", i, "OUT: ", stdo
    # comm.barrier()
    # r = comm.allgather(stdo) #Causes infinite loop because any number above 4 processors after the first iteration will never exit the while loop
#if any collective operation or barrier is removed, it will work properly
if rank == 0:
    print "Num Proc is", num_proc, "Time is",  MPI.Wtime() - start_time
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem here, but… `communicate` implicitly calls `wait`, so there's no reason to call it yourself.

Comment: There are a number of `ulimit` settings that can cause this. The most obvious one is `-u`, which limits the number of processes available to a normal user, but any number of other things could cause it. Are you checking `a.returncode` anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Popen's first argument (what's passed to bash) needs to be a string. I also always do shell=True.  If you're the one writing the script you know what the code should be doing, so it'll be safe to run.

```
cmd = 'echo HELLO'
a = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
```